# Intercept ajax requests coming from iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, iframe

Can I intercept ajax-requests from an iframe on the "parent" site?
I would need a solution, where i don't modify the site within the iframe?
(of course both are in the same domain)

best regards

Comment: Why do you want to do this?